# What do these symbols mean in html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

I found this code when surfing through jquery tooltip. Please Suggest why we use certain code and what does it mean?

```
 <pre class="prettyprint">
 &lt;head&#62;

   &lt;script&#62;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
            contentAsHTML: true
        });
    });
&lt;/script&#62;
&lt;/head&#62;
&lt;body&#62;

&lt;div class="tooltip" title="&amp;lt;img src=&amp;quot;my-  image.png&amp;quot; /&amp;gt; &amp;lt;strong&amp;gt; This text is in bold case   !&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;"&gt; 
    This div has a tooltip with HTML when you hover over it!
&lt;/div&#62;

&lt;/body&#62;</pre>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that your entered is html encoded, it means that with html special characters:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
            contentAsHTML: true
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="tooltip" title="<img src=my-image.png /> <strong> This text is in bold case!</strong>"> 
    This div has a tooltip with HTML when you hover over it!
</div>

</body></pre>
```

ISO-8859-1 is the default character in HTML 4.01, please see the [list of XML and HTML character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) for more information.

For instance, `"&lt;" is "<" (less-than sign, U+003C)`

The code you tried to understand creates tooltip when user put mouse on the div with the text

> This div has a tooltip with HTML when you hover over it!

The content of the toolpit is between the title tag, so

> `<img src=my-image.png /> <strong> This text is in bold case!</strong>`

img is to show a picture ant the text between strong... is strong :-)

Comment: it describes everything actually, can you please tell how did you do that?

Comment: @clement It is fabulous!

Answer (score 0):

They are HTML entities, used to show symbols on the page, such as those that are actual html code. So `< >` as an HTML entity is `&lt; &gt;` (less than, greater than). `&copy;` is the copyright symbol etc

Comment: Yeah I know little about &copy!Thanku@MattyF

Answer (score 0):

`&lt;` is used for the [< symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less-than_sign). Similary `&gt;` is used for the [> symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater-than_sign). These are known as HTML entities.

On a side note you can refer **[this](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/greater-than-sign-inequality-ascii-code-62.html)** for future reference.

Comment: Wow!That is huge collection!

Comment: @sia:- Indeed, just thought that it may help you to understand that more clearly!

Comment: Great! definately:)@Rahul Tripathi

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this resource for a better understanding http://w3schools.com/HTML/html_entities.asp

Comment: Thanku! It is the simplest way!

Answer (score 0):

Those are html entities.
Reserved characters in `HTML` must be replaced with character entities.
Characters, not present on your keyboard, can also be replaced by entities.